# Xcode does not generate dSYM file

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, build-settings

In my iOS Project, I have set the `Generate Debug Symbols` to be `Yes`, but the .dYSM file is not created in DerivedData folder. I am running this application on my iPhone. Because I need it to map it to do the time profiler, because time profiler shows all the symbols in hex address. That has to be symbolicated to identify the time taking tasks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40):

I went through this [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/LocatingSymbolsforYourData.html). This helped me. This says to set the `Debug Information format` to be `DWARF AND DSYM` in target build settings.

This apple doc says the following:

> By default, Xcode saves symbols as dSYM bundles in the Build folder.
>   Xcode creates the default dSYM bundle path by adding the extension
>   .dSYM to the executable name. To generate dSYM bundles in Xcode, go to
>   the Build Settings area for your project, and select Debug Information
>   Format > Dwarf with dSYM File in the Build Options section